# Angular2 component's "this" is undefined when executing callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular

I have a component which calls a service to fetch data from a RESTful endpoint. This service needs to be given a callback function to execute after fetching said data.

The issue is when I try use the callback function to append the data to the existing data in a component's variable, I get a `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`. Why is `this` undefined?

TypeScript version: Version 1.8.10

Controller code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ApiService} from '...'

@Component({
    ...
})
export class MainComponent {

    private messages: Array<any>;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}

    getMessages(){
        this.apiService.getMessages(gotMessages);
    }

    gotMessages(messagesFromApi){
        messagesFromApi.forEach((m) => {
            this.messages.push(m) // EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? (You can check that with `tsc -v`)

Comment: The exception because forEach. Use For-of instead.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
getMessages() {
    this.apiService.getMessages(this.gotMessages.bind(this));
}
```

What happens here is that you pass the `gotMessages` as a callback, when that is being executed the scope is different and so the `this` is not what you expected.
The `bind` function returns a new function that is bound to the `this` you defined.

You can, of course, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) there as well:

```
getMessages() {
    this.apiService.getMessages(messages => this.gotMessages(messages));
}
```

I prefer the `bind` syntax, but it's up to you.

A third option so to bind the method to begin with:

```
export class MainComponent {
    getMessages = () => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or

```
export class MainComponent {
    ...

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
        this.getMessages = this.getMessages.bind(this);
    }

    getMessages(){
        this.apiService.getMessages(gotMessages);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! And thanks for explaining why this happens.

Comment: Thank you! The fact that OOP-style is leaking javascript specifics (bind) is tragic.

Comment: Totally argee with @skfd that the .bind( this ) should be default TypeScript behaviour, since we are programming OO! :-) But thanks, I'll remember to add this to all callbacks on class member functions now, which is always case in my case, since ...

Answer (score 21):

Or you can do it like this

```
gotMessages(messagesFromApi){
    let that = this // somebody uses self 
    messagesFromApi.forEach((m) => {
        that.messages.push(m) // or self.messages.push(m) - if you used self
    })
}
```

Comment: You are my hero

Answer (score 19):

Because you're just passing the function reference in `getMessages` you don't have the right `this` context.

You can easily fix that by using a lambda which automatically binds the right `this` context for the use inside that anonymous function:

```
getMessages(){
    this.apiService.getMessages((data) => this.gotMessages(data));
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Simplest and efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, resolved by using **() =>** { } instead **function()**

Comment: this does not add any information to the existing answers

Answer (score 0):

Please define function

```
gotMessages = (messagesFromApi) => {
  messagesFromApi.forEach((m) => {
    this.messages.push(m)
  })
}
```

Comment: this does not add any information to the existing answers