# Angular Promise with multiple handlers

Tags: angular

Is it possible to provide multiple handlers for the same Promise in Angular2? For example, if I was designing a Service and wanted to allow multiple clients to subscribe to it and be notified when the Promise was resolved?

Note, I'm not asking how to return multiple values from a service nor am I asking how to chain Promises.

Comment: you simply call `then` on the original promise, like this `let p = new Promise(fn); p.then(callback1); p.then(callback2);`. this is not chaining as you're adding callbacks to the original promise, not the one returned by `then`

Comment: @Maximus - and if I don't know how how many callbacks there are? I assume I would be storing callbacks in an array?

Comment: so what does it change? `let a = [fn1, fn2]; let p = new Promise(fn); a.forEach(fn => {p.then(fn)});`

Comment: @Maximus - Agree, it doesn't. However, there is a big limitation. Inside the callback, `this` is undefined, and no longer refers to Component instance. Assuming I want to do anything other than `console.log` the result, I need `this` to be defined.

Comment: I didn't understand how `this` is undefined, can you update your question details with code?

Comment: @Maximus - Resolved using bind, described here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38245500](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38245500)

Comment: yeah, but you don't need `bind` with arrow functions. if my answer helped, I can post it

Comment: I implemented your solution. I included the arrows. `this` was still resolving to a different scope. It's all working now using `bind` explicitly.

Comment: show your code please, I also posted my suggestion as an answer

Comment: `private callbacks: Array<any> = new Array();

public asyncCall(): Promise<any> {
    var p = this.doAsyncCall();
    let a = this.callbacks;

    a.forEach(fn => {
        p.then(fn);
    });

    return p;
}`

Comment: I don't see `bind` used in your code.

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote or accept my answer

Comment: just wondering, what's the reason for not accepting my answer if you used the solution provided by it?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is not not add callbacks to the promise returned by the `then`, but rather add them to the original promise. Something like that will do:

```
let a = [fn1, fn2]; 
let p = new Promise(fn); 
a.forEach(fn => {p.then(fn)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let callbacks = [fn1, fn2 ...]
promise.then((resolvedValue) => { 
           callbacks.forEach(fn => fn(resolvedValue)); 
        }
```