# Angular 2: property becomes underfined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, binding

The problem is that the property which is passed to the view child becomes `undefined`:

*Parent component*:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-searchbox',
    template: `
            <app-artifact-list [artifacts]="searchResults"></app-artifact-list>
    `
})
export class SearchboxComponent implements OnInit {

    // explicitly initialize the property 
    // the same effect with constructor initialization
    searchResults: Artifact[] = [new Artifact()];

    constructor(private artifactService: ArtifactService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.pollService(this.artifactService.findByQuery('guice'));
    }

    private pollService(request: Observable<Artifact[]>) {
        return request.subscribe(this.fillInResults);
    }

    private fillInResults(result: Artifact[]) {
        result.forEach(console.log);
        for (let obj of result) {
            // this.searchResults is undefined! why?
            this.searchResults.push(obj);
        }
    }

}
```

*Child component*:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-artifact-list',
    template: `
            <h1>{{_artifacts | json}}</h1>
    `
})
export class ArtifactListComponent implements OnChanges {

    private _artifacts: Artifact[] = [];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log('Property changed');
    }

    @Input()
    set artifacts(artifacts: Artifact[]) {
        console.error('Property changed');
        this._artifacts = artifacts;
    }

}
```

During constructor call I see that the property is properly initialized but in the callback method it becomes `undefined`.

Isn't it somehow related to `this`? Maybe `this.searchResults` refers to anything else in the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation into `this` when it is used in scope of "function references", I found out that actually `this` refers to another object. I love javascript :)

So the workaround is:

```
private pollService(request: Observable<Artifact[]>) {
    return request.subscribe(
        this.fillInResults.bind(this)
    );
}

private fillInResults(result: any) {
    result.forEach(console.log);
    for (let obj of result) {
        this.searchResults.push(obj);
    }
}
```

Or to use fat arrow function:

```
private pollService(request: Observable<Artifact[]>) {
    return request.subscribe(
        result => this.fillInResults(result)
    );
}

private fillInResults(result: any) {
    result.forEach(console.log);
    for (let obj of result) {
        this.searchResults.push(obj);
    }
}
```

See this question for detailed explanation: [Angular2 component's “this” is undefined when executing callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function)