# Storing ag-grid rowclicked event data Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am trying to store the event data from the `onRowClicked` event in a Component member. So that when the user hits a button it will be deleted. However when I try accessing it from the delete callback the member variable is undefined.

```
export class OilTypesComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
 selectedOil : any;
 gridOptions: GridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

 ngOnInit() {
 this.gridOptions = {
      ...
      onCellEditingStopped: this.cellEdited,
      onRowClicked: this.rowClicked
    }
 }
...
 rowClicked(event){
    this.selectedOil = event.data;
 }

delete(){
    console.log(`Deleting ${this.selectedOil.manufacturer} //this.selectedOil is undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a scoping issue when passing in the callbacks as shown here:
[Angular2 component's "this" is undefined when executing callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function)

What I ended up doing for both callbacks

```
this.gridOptions = {
  ...
  onCellEditingStopped: this.cellEdited.bind(this),
  onRowClicked: this.rowClicked.bind(this)
}
```