# Property always undefined when accessing it in Event Handler from SignalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, signalr

I have built an angular application and I am using signalR to get notifications.

For the signalR stuff i have installed "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.4".

In the Angular App I have built a service that handles all notifications that are sent over signalR:

```
private _hubConnection: HubConnection;

numberX: number = 0;

constructor() {
  this.createConnection();
  this.registerOnServerEvents();
  this.startConnection();
}

private createConnection() {
  this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(someURL).build();
}

private startConnection(): void {
  this._hubConnection.start();
}

private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
  this._hubConnection.on('Notify', (data: any) => {
    this.numberX++;
  });
}
```

When I get an event from signalR the event handler is actually called, when I send something to the console output it is actually written to the console.

But when I try to access a member property (in this case numberX), I always get an exception telling me that numberX is undefined, even I define it at the very start.

Could this be some kind of scope thing?

**EDIT:**
The solution from Kenzk447 actually works for my given scenario. But this would not work when I go one step further by not just increasing a number, but using an EventEmitter that can be consumed by components:

**In the service:**

```
someEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
const $self = this;
this._hubConnection.on('ErrorMessage', (data: any) => {
     $self.someEvent.emit(data);
});
```

}

**In the component:**

```
notificationCount: number = 0;

this.notificationService.someEvent.subscribe(this.onSomeEvent);

onSomeEvent(data: any) {
    this.notificationCount++;
}
```

When doing this, 'this' in the component is undefined and I cannot access properties of the component.

**EDIT 2:**

Ok I got it working with
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function)

The trick is to bind the eventHandler.

Nevertheless I will accept the answer because it worked in my given example and pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was researched on SignalR repo, and i [found](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/release/2.2/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts#L452):

```
methods.forEach((m) => m.apply(this, invocationMessage.arguments));
```

Issue here: `m.apply(this,...`, SignalR trying to impose 'this' as HubConnection class instance. So, my solution:

```
private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
    const $self = this;
    this._hubConnection.on('Notify', (data: any) => {
         $self.numberX++;
    });
}
```