# Can't execute function inside custom form validation.. why?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular11

I have a Reactive Form in Angular 11 and I'm trying to execute a date parsing function inside the custom validator of my form but, I get an error on my browser terminal that says that the function is not defined.. It seems that the validator runs before the function definition.. but why? is there a solution to this?

My app works, I just repeated the code of the function inside the custom validator and everything is good.. but I shouldn't have to repeat code...

the constructor of my .ts:

```
constructor(private navbarService: NavbarService) {
    this.navbarService.showNavbar(true);
    this.placeholderDate = new Date;

    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
        fechaDesde: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})$/)
        ]),
        fechaHasta: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})$/),
        ]),
    }, [this.dateValidators])

}
```

My date parsing function in the same .ts file:

```
parseToDateFormat(date: string): Date {

    const destructurDate = date.split('-');
    if (destructurDate[0].length === 1) destructurDate[0] = '0' + destructurDate[0];
    if (destructurDate[1].length === 1) destructurDate[1] = '0' + destructurDate[1];
    let parsedDate = destructurDate.join('-');
    const result = new Date(parsedDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
    return result;
}
```

My dateValidaors() function (all in the same components ts:

```
dateValidators(form: FormGroup) {
    let fechaFrom = form.get('fechaDesde').value;
    let fechaTo = form.get('fechaHasta').value;
    fechaFrom = this.parseToDateFormat(fechaFrom);
    fechaTo = this.parseToDateFormat(fechaTo);
    if (fechaFrom <= fechaTo) return null;

}
```

the error is :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: can't access property "parseToDateFormat", this is undefined
> dateValidators@http://localhost:4200/main.js:1811:5

Again, my solution was to just copy paste the logic of my parsing function inside the validator, but repeating code.

Can someone explain please?

Comment: maybe this answer can be helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juan, is how say Abdelmak, that's:your function dateValidator goes

```
dateValidators() {
    return (form: FormGroup) => {
     ...your code...
     ..here you can use "this"
   }
}
```

You use the validator like

```
  searchForm = new FormGroup(
  {
    ...
  },[this.dateValidators()] //<--see the parenthesis
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand a lot more, and it is very simple answer!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like scope issue when validator is executed `this.dateValidators` there is no reference of your component is present that is why `parseToDateFormat` is undefined. I would suggest to create a validator class and define static methods in that class like

```
export class DateValidator {
    public static parseToDateFormat(date: string): Date {
        const destructurDate = date.split('-');
        if (destructurDate[0].length === 1) destructurDate[0] = '0' + destructurDate[0];
        if (destructurDate[1].length === 1) destructurDate[1] = '0' + destructurDate[1];
        let parsedDate = destructurDate.join('-');
        const result = new Date(parsedDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
        return result;
    
    }
    public static dateValidators() {
        return (form: AbstractControl) => {
            let fechaFrom = form.get('fechaDesde').value;
            let fechaTo = form.get('fechaHasta').value;
            fechaFrom = DateValidator.parseToDateFormat(fechaFrom);
            fechaTo = DateValidator.parseToDateFormat(fechaTo);
            if (fechaFrom <= fechaTo) return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and in your form group initialize your date validator as

```
this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
  fechaDesde: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})$/)
  ]),
  fechaHasta: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})$/),
  ]),
}, [DateValidator.dateValidators()])
```