# How do I make sure that a function is not undefined in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined-function

I'm sorry for the terrible title, but I have the following situation:
I'm using angular with Knova node package to create a webapp for my thesis work to finish Uni.

I have two components on one of my pages: the first one being a navbar, and the second the edior itself. I have a button in the navbar, that I add an eventlistner to in my EditorComponent class, so when I click it, I can initiate the importOwnSave method to import shapes from an xml file.
I tell you all this to make the situation more clear.

So the heart of my problem is, that I have a method:

```
addTransformerListeners(shape: Shape): void {
const component = this;
this.stage.on('click', function (e) {
  e.evt.preventDefault();
  if (!this.clickStartShape) {
    return;
  }
  if (e.target._id == this.clickStartShape._id) {
     {...}
  }
  else {
     {...}
  }
});
}
```

which when called from another method, at the end of my file, but in the same class (class EditorComponent) breaks:

```
importOwnSave(): void {    

    var component = this;

    {... variable value settings, I'm 100% sure this is nothing important ...}

    var addTransformers = this.addTransformerListeners; //<- this becomes undefined

    console.log(addTransformers, this.addTransformerListeners);

    {...}
}
```

the console log shows that addTransformers and this.addTransformerListeners are undefined, and anywhere I try to call that method it's undefined, and throws an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.addTransformerListeners is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.importOwnSave (editor.component.ts:929)
```

The good part about this is that in another method, used to generate a rectangle to the canvas, invokes the method just fine:

```
addRectangle(): Rect {
    const rectangle = this.shapeService.rectangle();
    this.shapes.push(rectangle);
    this.layer.add(rectangle);
    this.addTransformerListeners(rectangle); //<-
    return rectangle;
}
```

when addRectangle is called, this.addTransformer has the correct value of **ƒ addTransformerListeners(shape)**, and runs as intended

I'm really sorry to bother you, reading this with my stupid code, but I'm stuck on so many levels I can not even describe, and after searching a lot, nobody seems to have had quite the same issue.
If you are considering wirting an answer, know that everything might help, even the things you would consider as a basic element of working in typescript, I could have easily missed something important, as I'm not *quite* the professional using angular and TS. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [ask]. 
You should probably work on converting the code here into a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](//tsplay.dev/WJRXZW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, pseudocode, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  If you can't get standalone code, you could try to provide a link to a configured web IDE project.

Comment: It's really hard to debug with the information you have given. I'll give it a shot though. Can you console log 'this' and see what comes up there? It feels like you could have ran into this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function

Comment: As another way to debug, declare addTransformerListeners as static method and instead of calling the method using `this.addTransformerListeners(shape)` call it `EditorComponent.addTransformerListeners(shape)` as see if it works

Comment: You aren't passing a argument to your function where as your function strictly takes has a param, possibly the issue?

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha Oh my f##ing God, you are dead on! 'this' was not the component, but rather the button that I threw the event listner on... I feel like I should have caught that but I never knew something like this could happen. Thank you soooo much, with the `.bind(this)` chaining on the event listner it works great! Thank you!

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, I'll make sure to follow all guidelines and to make a minimal reproducible example, or a code that can be dropped into the TypeScript playground (never knew this existed :/ ) next time if and when I have to open another question. Sorry that this question was so badly presented, and thanks for everything!